# Order Mail is not sending

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, cron, order-email, magento-1.9.2.0

I am using Magento 1.9.2.2. When a customer place order then confirmation mail is not sending.

My **Sales Emails** section is as like below

[image]

I installed this (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) Extension for Cron. Below is the screenshot of this extension

[image]

Below is the screenshot of **System Cron** tab.

[image]

Below is the screenshot of **core_email_queue** table of database

[image]

Below is the screenshot of **Cron** setup of my **server**

[image]

Cron is running. I am getting notification when cron runs.
Can anyone help me in this regard ??

**Update**

I found below codes in .htaccess file.

```
###########################################
## Deny access to cron.php
    <Files cron.php>

############################################
## uncomment next lines to enable cron access with base HTTP authorization
## http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html
##
## Warning: .htpasswd file should be placed somewhere not accessible from the web.
## This is so that folks cannot download the password file.
## For example, if your documents are served out of /usr/local/apache/htdocs
## you might want to put the password file(s) in /usr/local/apache/.

        #AuthName "Cron auth"
        #AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
        #AuthType basic
        #Require valid-user

############################################

        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all

    </Files>
```

Comment: run yoururl/cron.php  what output comes?

Comment: www.example.com/cron.php

Comment: Thanks @denishvachhani for your reply.  I am getting notification when cron runs.Thanks

Comment: yes but url/cron.php run in browser 404 comes???

Comment: I am getting (**Forbidden

You do not have permission to access this document**) when I am running url/cron.php in browser. Thanks

Comment: what permission you give to cron.php? give 644

Comment: Thanks @denishvachhani. Permission is  **rw- r-- r--** for cron.php.

Comment: now work? or getting same error?

Comment: open your htaccess file search cron.php tag defined there?

Comment: Thanks. I added a update section in actual question. You can find .htaccess file contents there.

Comment: check my answers.

Comment: check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comment out the bellow two lines in .htaccess

```
    <Files cron.php>

############################################
## uncomment next lines to enable cron access with base HTTP authorization
## http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html
##
## Warning: .htpasswd file should be placed somewhere not accessible from the web.
## This is so that folks cannot download the password file.
## For example, if your documents are served out of /usr/local/apache/htdocs
## you might want to put the password file(s) in /usr/local/apache/.

        #AuthName "Cron auth"
        #AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
        #AuthType basic
        #Require valid-user

############################################

        #Order allow,deny
        #Deny from all

    </Files>
```

Replace code with this. because .htacess dont allow cron and access denied from this code.

Try with this command in cpanel in cron

```
wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.example.com/cron.php
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I modified .htaccess file as per your instruction. But  Cron is running as like before. Order mail is not sending like previous. Did you see the screen shot of **core_email_queue** table of Database ?? I think the problem is there. On the other hand I am running **scheduler_cron.sh** file. Issue can be there. Thanks

Comment: Your solution is working but Customer mail is not sending. Customer is not getting any mail. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using curl to call the shell file. This is not possible (normally)

Either

- Let curl call cron.php and uncomment the block in htaccess (and add allow for local host only)
- or set cron to let she'll execute the cron.sh file directly

  - or let php call the file directly (eg php -f /pathtofile/cron.php) and set this as command in cron

Should solve the cron to run

Comment: Currently mail is sending but customer is not getting any mail while he is ordering. Thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer that helped you. And raise a new question. Or google first. There can be many reasons.